# Is the 20 concurrent callout to external system going to be a practical issue for me?

Tags: callout

I saw 20 concurrent callouts limit to external to salesforce org. In our organization we are using direct callout for order placement to on-prem system. Does that mean our salesforce application  will support only 20 users  ?  I suggested to use continuation server but did anyone faced this apex limit at all ?

Answer (score 7):

It's 20 *concurrent* (open at the same time) connections. Connections are usually short-lived and very sporadic when talking about users using the system. I don't think I've ever seen an org run into this limit, and it can certainly support far more than 20 *users*, since those connections won't be open most of the time. I doubt you'd run into any trouble at all until well into the thousands-of-users range, and even then, only if your app is *very* chattery and/or your service is *very* slow. The simple reason is, your users don't work that fast, so if your service runs at a decent speed, there won't be time for there to be 20 active connections. If this becomes a problem, then you could explore alternatives, but I wouldn't try to engineer your way out of a problem you don't have.

Comment: I will give an example if that helps.  I have a order placement webservice  with a timeout of 120 seconds.  During one of the peakhour  my webservice is responding around 100 seconds due to  some payment gateway slowness. In this case  how many  order placement calls will be honoured by salesforce concurrently

Comment: Almost 2 minutes for your payment gateway to respond? I think you should consider another payment gateway provider or an alternate solution where salesforce doesn't have to hold a connection open for that length of time.

Comment: @munimanjunath If you had to take two minutes per credit card transaction, your sales would grind to a halt. *Real* services, like PayPal and Authorize.net, perform in a fraction of a second. However, hypothetically, if you really needed to, you could build a server farm, make a ton of DNS entries to trick salesforce.com to thinking they're all separate hosts, then round-robin connect to each of them to provide load balancing. It's possible to engineer ways around the limits, but the *real* answer would still be: get a provider that can provide near-instant responses.

Comment: @sfdcfox  our order processing callout average around 8 sec but still if 30 people place an order simultneously I believe 10 of them will be rejected by salesforce itself due to apex limit.  Only way is to use future method or use continuation approach